# RPG skill system

Tags: java

im working on a RPG system for my friend, and I was wondering on how to make the skills system, should I use ArrayList skills as a type and write every skill down, into a XML or in to a class?

Example

```
Skill s = new Skill();
ArrayList<Skill> skills = new ArrayList<Skill>();
s.name = "Dodge";
s.description = "Dodge a attack.";
s.requirements = "Dex +30";
skills.put(s);
```

Or something like...

```
Dodge dodge = new Dodge();
Skill s = new Skill();
ArrayList<Skill> skills = new ArrayLst<Skill>();
s.name = dodge.getName();
s.description = dodge.getDescription();
s.requirements = dodge.getRequirements();
skills.put(s);
```

Comment: Removed the `rpg` tag, because it refers to the RPG programming language not the abbreviation for Role Playing Game.

Comment: In the future, what tag should I use? Would I use rp-game or something other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skills in RPGs are usually used as 'data' to determine the effectiveness of some kind of in-game action.  As such, skills are an easy candidate for a data driven design.

Rather than hardcoding it, use some method of having the skills populated from a set of data, and have the game mechanics look for these skill values after having read them in.  XML is a good candidate for this.  It is a bit verbose, but a lot of editors/IDEs recognize it and java has parser support for it built in.

Comment: Should I use the same method for character classes & races? Or should I hardcode them?

Comment: Same.  Class/Race is just data that maps to some in-game effect.  If you use a data-centric model for these kinds of things, it will be easy to add new classes / races based off of the currently implemented ones.

Comment: Ok, thanks :) Now I only need to figure out how to implement everything into a working order. On to the drawing board!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_XML_Processing for some XML parsing documentation.

Comment: Regarding XML parsing, perhaps XStream would be more appropriate in this case

Answer (score 2):

I would use XML reader from Aion-lightning project. It is easy to use and scopes for larger sets of xml files.

Comment: Can you please include links and sources about this program?

Answer (score 1):

Well, i would rather do XML instead of a class.
Mainly because you don't have to recompile your game everytime you tweak skill values.

Depending on how advanced you want it, check out RunUO. Its a open source mmorpg project for simulating a Ultima Online server.